# MySQL procedure and clear same statement return different value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I make simple procedure in MySQL like here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `findId` (IN adr varchar(45), out id int)
BEGIN
    set @id := (select id from `stocker` where adresa = adr);
END
```

Also, I make same procedure like:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `findId` (IN adr varchar(45), out id int)
BEGIN
    (select id from `stocker` where adresa = adr) into id;
END
```

After I called this with MySQL, value for OUT parameter is null...
I test this with clear statement:

```
set @idd := (select id from `stocker` where adresa = "Some street");
select @idd;
```

I call procedure like this:

```
set @id = 0;
call stock.pronadjiId("Gajibina 6", @id);
select @id;
```

Can you help me to understand, where I make mistake?

Comment: Use `SET id = (SELECT id FROM stocker WHERE adresa = adr);` [Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ee368d8d30a806a407207f0cbbd47a6)

Comment: @GarethD Same problem with that

Comment: Does this work? `SET id = (SELECT s.id FROM stocker AS s WHERE s.adresa = adr);` If so, I think the issue is that you reference to `id` in the select query was ambiguous between the column `id` and the parameter `id`, by introducing the alias, you remove this ambiguity, and you know that you are using the column reference. This does appear to work as expected for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ca5b3d971270a15da8b82f7379dfe5a

Comment: @GarethD Yes, this is it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter names vs. the column names. You have `id` both as parameter name and as a column name in same query.

Instead of using user defined variables and `OUT` parameters to return the values from a procedure, it is better just to return a result set with the value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `findId` (IN in_adr varchar(45))
BEGIN
select id from `stocker` where adresa = in_adr;
END
```

Comment: Than I have more complicated code in program. I want to send variable in code and after procedure call I must value in variable.